# Batch opening a webpage using the default browser

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I make a batch file open a webpage that is specified in the code with the default browser?

I found this, but it only works with Firefox and if a user doesn’t have Firefox then it won't work.

```
"C:\Program Files\PROGRAM" "C:\Program Files\REFERNCE FILE TO OPEN IN PROGRAM"|"C:\Program Files\PROGRAM"|"C:\Program Files\PROGRAM"|"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://google.com
```

Comment: why dont you use "url" type of file? http://file.org/extension/url

Comment: @PavelJanicek I don't think he wanted extra software to do this. and it is easier to do it without.

Comment: Yeah, I think the same. But basically, "URL" file type is a text file which upon doubleclick opens given URL in default browser. From user point ovf view, it does the same as the bat file

Comment: You do know URL isn't the file type HTML is the file type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have is a bit overkill. Try using the following. It will use the default browser.

```
START Http://www.google.com
```

I have tested it on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by 09stephenb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657381/batch-opening-a-webpage-using-the-default-browser/22657475#22657475) would only open with your default browser (which is not necessarily Chrome).

If you want it to open *only* in Google Chrome, you can add the location of your Chrome `.exe` like this --

```
start "" "C:\Your-Chrome-Path-Here\chrome.exe" https://google.com
```

**Edit:**

- Example of path to Chrome `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`
- You can find your Chrome path by opening Task Manager while Chrome is running, and displaying the "Command line" filter

[image: Task Manager]
*Source: [file.net](https://www.file.net/process/chrome.exe.html)*

Comment: Perhaps provide an ***example*** for the location of Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This example should open any URL with the standard web browser.
If the URL is very long or contains "&" characters, it is necessary to enclose it in quotation marks and the URL must be enclosed in quotation marks when used with the SET command.
The quotation marks after START are required in this example.

```
SET WEB_URL="https://stackoverflow.com/tour"
START "" %WEB_URL%
```